# How can i use DataBinding for TextView?

Tags: kotlin, data-binding, viewmodel

i have a problem, i dont know how to use DataBinding for TextView. i made a DataBinding for Glide and it success, but for TextView i dont know how to do it

this is the code

```
viewModel2.shouldShowImageProfile.observe(this) {
        Glide.with(binding.root)
            .load(it)
            .circleCrop()
            .into(binding.rivProfile)
    }

    viewModel2.shouldShowUsername.observe(this){
        TextView.with(binding.root) <- the TextView
            .load(it)
            .into(binding.tvHello)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my answer making an assumption about `shouldShowUsername`, but as that's your `String` value, you can do something like this:

```
viewModel2.shouldShowUsername.observe(this) { shouldShowUsername ->
    binding.tvHello.isVisible = !shouldShowUsername.isNullOrEmpty()
    binding.tvHello.text = shouldShowUsername
}
```

That'll cause your `TextView` to only be displayed when `shouldShowUsername` has a proper value then take that value and assign it to the `TextView`. If you want the `TextView` to always show up, you can skip that first line within the block.

Comment: my shouldShowUsername is MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

Comment: Ah, got it! I updated my answer accordingly, @Samuel.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use observe method on variables of viewmodel you can use data binding and change value of textview from the xml directly, so that you dont have to manually write **binding.tvUserName.text = it.value**. Below code shows example for usuage of data binding with xml and viewmodel.
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.kotlinbasics.android_architecture.mvvm_architecture.ChatViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        tools:context=".android_architecture.mvvm_architecture.UserOneFragment">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/etMessageToSecond"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_field_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/enter_message"
            android:padding="@dimen/_7sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCurrentMessage"
            android:text="@{`Current Message: `+viewModel.latestMessageFromFirst}"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etMessageToSecond" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

In the above example I am printing the live text in textview which user writes in the edittext field. Whenever user writes in edittext, its value gets updated in the viewmodel and textview access that value on runtime.
For image thing, you can do like, you can create custom binding adapter which updates the image. Example:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivEmailVerification"
            loadImageFromUrl="@{viewModel.emailVerifyImageUrl}"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvIsEmailValid"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7" />
```

and on BindingAdpater

```
@BindingAdapter("loadImageFromUrl")
fun ImageView.loadImageFromUrl(imageUrl: String) {
    Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(this)
}
```